# HTML-Canvas - JavaScript-Animating/Drawing

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have this :

http://jsfiddle.net/geduardcatalin/6Lg6ymt3/

How can I make the second line to start from center and stop at the bottom left corner like the first one is stoping where I want ( in the center ) ?

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var canvasWidth = canvas.width;
var canvasHeight = canvas.height;

var i = 0;
var j = 0;
var k = 0;
var l = 0;

function drawLine1() {
  i = i + 1;
  j = j + 1;
  x1 = i;
  y1 = j;

  if (i >= 149) {
    i = 149;
  }

  if (j >= 149) {
    j = 149;
  }

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;
  ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(x1, y1);
  ctx.stroke();
}

function drawLine2() {
  k = k - 1;
  l = l + 1;
  x2 = k;
  y2 = l;

  if (k >= 299) {
    k = 299;
  }

  if (l >= 299) {
    l = 299;
  }

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;
  ctx.moveTo(150, 150);
  ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);
  ctx.stroke();
}

function drawLines() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
  drawLine1();
  drawLine2();
  //setTimeout(drawLine2, 0000);
}

setInterval(drawLines, 40);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html {
  background-color: #555555;
}
#wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 70px auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <canvas id="myCanvas" height="300px" width="300px"></canvas>
  <p id="demo"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to illustrate this, because I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: If I add 149 to x2 and y2 at "ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);", it goes from the center to bottom right but it continues another 149 px in each direction. @Snorlax, please check the jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/geduardcatalin/6Lg6ymt3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `k` and `l` in the Line2 should both start at 150, and change `draw Line2()` to this:

Here is the updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Lg6ymt3/56/).

```
function drawLine2(){
    k = k - 1;
    l = l + 1;
    x2 = k;
    y2 = l;

    if ( k <= 0 ){
        k = 0;
    }
    if ( l >= 299 ){
        l = 299;
    }

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.moveTo(150, 150);
    ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

Comment: Take notice that right now you are drawing for ever. You should consider have a flag to check when to stop.

Comment: Yes, I know that! Thank you again! :D

Comment: It's just for learning purposes. I just started a few days ago to learn JavaScript and I can stop. Is too damn good!

Answer (score 0):

This is because your `l` variable is stopping at `299` but `k` goes on forever. `k` is going from `0` to `-299` (and not `0` to `299`), so to fix it you want to change it's condition to:

```
if ( k <= -299 ){
    k = -299;
}
```

And have the correct `ctx.lineTo(x2 + 149, y2 + 149);` you mentioned in your comment.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes, now it make sense!